# Yosemite crashes, goes to a black screen and then wakes on a login screen?

Tags: macos, crash, adobe

Ive got an issue on a mac mini running 10.10.5 where it will crash, the screens goes black and about 30 seconds later the screens wake up again, on the login page.

I believe the issue is being caused by either Adobe Indesign or Adobe Photoshop. (As from what i can tell from past experiences with this happening these apps always seem to be used at the time when i have the issue)

I was running the 2015 version of these softwares, but have since updated to 2017 (as part of the subscription service) as i thought this may resolve the issue, but i hasnt.

I have taken notes of the time the issue occurred, is there somewhere i can look in the logs to see what might be causing it ?

Comment: Best guess is it's running out of VRAM. Try reducing the amount it's allowed to use, in prefs; prevent it from using hardware acceleration; or don't use any other OpenGL app at the same time.

Comment: @Tetsujin is VRAM the same as the GPU ? This particular mac mini although having 16gb of RAM only has a 256MB GPU

Comment: Yes, GPU RAM. I don't know if the minis have dedicated or shared RAM but it might be worth switching off hardware acceleration altogether & see how it goes for a while. On a low end GPU you may not even notice any performance difference.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin ill give it a try. The later mac minis (>2014 i think) have shared GPU. The earlier ones have a dedicated GPU, but in this instance the machine only has 256MB of dedicated GPU